# EntityFramework Core reference causes compiler error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've added the entityframework core reference into my full framework core webapi project but it causes an error.  I have registered the db context in Startup.cs as shown in the screen shot below.  When I attempt to run it (using dotnet run) the code throws an error!  The error is shown below, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks, any help appreciated.

**Breaking line**

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext1>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext1")));
```

**Error**

```
>dotnet run
Project something (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6) will be compiled because inputs were modified Compiling something for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6

Compilation succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.4944030


Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:     Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at something.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invoke
Attr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection exportServices) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build() at something.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\tms-sime\src\something\Program.cs:line 15
```

[image: startup.cs file]

**Package file (project.json)**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
```

**Update**

I created the project like so

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assume you've done a clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes I have (within visual studio)

Comment: What does your package file look like?

Comment: I have updated my question with the project.json contents, hope this helps

Comment: Do you have any other projects that the main project depends upon? If so, chech their project.json for old references to the 1.0.0 version.

Comment: The webapi project I created, using .NET core (full framework)  is trying to use a class called BlaSystemDbContext which resides in a .NET 4.5.2 class library project.  This project (that has the BlaSystemDbContext class in it) uses EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: How did you create this project? When you run ```dotnet run``` it says ```.NETFramework,Version=v4.6```. Was this always the case? Do you get the same error running with VS?

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshots showing how I created the project.  I have an existing solution and then I selected create new project

Comment: Did the project build before you added EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still occurring, I just upgraded `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` in the NuGet Manager, so it helped me.